# Ubuntu 14.04 Add control + mouse click for right click

Tags: mouse, cinnamon

I have  a Mac mouse that only has the one click option, model: M5769.

I want to add a right click option like you would have on a Mac, by pressing control, and then pressing the mouse button.

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04. I run the Cinnamon environment.

Thanks for any help.
Med.

Comment: Please...I can't be the only person who has wanted to add an extra button for a mouse...anyone have any ideas?