# Ubuntu to Mac: Ctrl+Click ---> Right Click

Tags: 15.10, macbook-pro

I finally convinced my wife to put Ubuntu on her Macbook.  Unfortunately, she **strongly** prefers the Mac approach to right clicking:  Ctrl+Button1.  I have the trackpad set up to do a two finger touch = right-click, but she isn't having it.

Can anyone **please, please, PLEASE** help me figure this out.  I've seen [this question posted before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522935/ubuntu-14-04-add-control-mouse-click-for-right-click), with no answers.

I also saw the `mouseemu` approach mentioned [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1895767), but it doesn't seem to work.

I also thought about using the built in System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Custom Shortcut, but it doesn't allow a "left click."

I also thought about using CCSM and xdotool, but couldn't figure out how to get two xdotool (xdotool xdotool key super+l; xdootool click 1)options to turn into one (xdotool click 3).  (Note: I switched the Ctrl key and the super/mac command key to make it more mac-like, hence the super+l).

If you have a workable solution -- please respond.  A Mac to Ubuntu conversion is at stake!

[Ubuntu 15.10; MacbookPro 9,2]

Comment: is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97748/how-do-i-bind-right-click-to-a-keyboard-shortcut) what you are looking for? (the link is an old askubuntu post, with answer)

Comment: Thanks WTF.  Unfortunately, she got frustrated and took it back before I could test!  I did try that briefly and it didn't work, but don't recall if I logged out/rebooted to see if it worked then.  I hope to have access to the computer again in the next few weeks... maybe...

Comment: Even though is not releveant this might help: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=921609
Scroll to the last post with: `gksudo gedit /etc/default/mouseemu` line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Under the section `"Input Class"` edit the options for `TapButton` so you have

```
Section "InputClass"

        Option          "TapButton1" "1"
        Option          "TapButton2" "3"
        Option          "TapButton3" "2"
```

This will enable right click and tap to click.

Comment: I FINALLY got the computer back -- and this worked!   Awesome!!!  One question - because I was wrong about the key that is actually used on the Mac side.  On the Mac side, the physical CTRL key (not the Mac/command) key is the one that performs the function of opening a link when paired with a mouse click.  What would the setup be to make this happen in a Ubuntu computer with the Super and CTRL button's switched?  That is, how do I do the same thing, but have the keyboard button FOR THIS FUNCTION ONLY be the Super key (which is set to the CTRL button)?

Comment: Whait, what? How does this achieve mapping ctrl+click to right click exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Both given answers didn't work for me. What worked for me was:

```
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=1
```

Put it in some file that is run at startup (e.g. `.bash`, `.zsh`)

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/861694

Comment: But it is not Ctrl-click that gives right-click in this solution

Answer (score 2):

The solution with `mouseemu` [from here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1895767) (and referenced in the question) works well for me on Lubuntu 18.10, as follows:

1. Install `mouseemu` and a dependency it does not list (which is a bug!):

   ```
   sudo apt install mouseemu makedev
   ```
2. Start `mouseemu` with the right configuration to use:

   ```
   sudo mouseemu -right 29 272
   ```

   It may take up to 5 seconds until the change takes effect. After that, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left-click should create a right-click.

Unfortunately, sometimes this stops working randomly after a few minutes. In such a case, this will repair it:

```
sudo killall -9 mouseemu
sudo mouseemu -right 29 272
```

Comment: Sadly, this technique cannot be used for Ctrl + tap on a touchscreen to create a right-click. Because touch events do not have keyboard scancodes (tested it [as shown here](https://superuser.com/a/828247)), which `mouseemu` expects for its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

On Mint, I had this section at the bottom of my my 50-synaptics.conf

```
# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Commenting out the option worked for me.

```
#Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
```

Seems a strange default!